Is a Catholic morally obliged to defend his reputation?
Is a Catholic morally obliged to defend his reputation (against, e.g., calumny, detraction, etc.)? If so, how is he to go about defending his reputation?

I'll offer a 200pt bounty if we get a quodlibet on this with 4 objections.

(I can't find the source for this at the moment, so this is a comment, not an answer.) Abstractly, it is good and humble to refrain from defending one's reputation (turning the other cheek). But there are situations where a defense is required, especially if refraining could  lead others to sin. For example, a parent who allows calumny might make it difficult for the children to obey the commandment to honor one's parents.

@PeterTurner Is defending the Catholic's spouse / parents "in scope" for this question?  If yes, that would become easier for that quodlibet.  BTW, I dropped a message for you in the Upper Room (cannot ping you from there).

@GratefulDisciple that seems like a strawman to me "Objection 1: It would seem that my mother does, indeed, wear army boots"

Is a Catholic morally obliged to defend his reputation?
The short answer is no.
Although Canon Law allows Catholics to defend their good reputation, it does not say that they are obliged to do so.

Can. 220 No one is permitted to harm illegitimately the good reputation which a person possesses nor to injure the right of any person to protect his or her own privacy.
Can. 221 §1. The Christian faithful can legitimately vindicate and defend the rights which they possess in the Church in the competent ecclesiastical forum according to the norm of law.
§2. If they are summoned to a trial by a competent authority, the Christian faithful also have the right to be judged according to the prescripts of the law applied with equity.
§3. The Christian faithful have the right not to be punished with canonical penalties except according to the norm of law.

A point in question can be seen in the life of St. Gerard Majella, who was accused of impregnating a young girl, yet never defended himself.

True sanctity must always be tested by the cross, and it was in 1754 that Gerard had to undergo a great trial, one that may well have merited for him the special power to assist mothers and their children. One of his works of zeal was that of encouraging and assisting girls who wanted to enter the convent. Often he would even secure the necessary dowry for some poor girl who could not otherwise be admitted into a religious order.
Neria Caggiano was one of the girls thus assisted by Gerard. However, she found convent life distasteful and within three weeks had returned home. To explain her action, Neria began to circulate falsehoods about the lives of the nuns, and when the good people of Muro refused to believe such stories about a convent recommended by Gerard, she determined to save her reputation by destroying the good name of her benefactor. Accordingly, in a letter to St. Alphonsus, the superior of Gerard, she accused the latter of sins of impurity with the young daughter of a family at whose house Gerard often stayed on his missionary journeys.
Gerard’s Conduct
Gerard was called by St. Alphonsus to answer the accusation. Instead of defending himself, however, he remained silent, following the example of his Divine Master. In the face of his silence, St. Alphonsus could do nothing but impose a severe penance on the young religious. Gerard was denied the privilege of receiving Holy Communion and forbidden all contact with outsiders.
It was not easy for Gerard to give up his labor on behalf of souls, but this was a small penance compared with being deprived of Holy Communion. He felt this so keenly that he even asked to be freed from the privilege of serving Mass for fear that the vehemence of his desire to receive would make him seize the consecrated Host from the very hands of the priest at the altar.
Sometime later Neria fell dangerously ill and wrote a letter to St. Alphonsus confessing that her charges against Gerard had been sheer fabrication and calumny. The Saint was filled with joy by the news of the innocence of his son. But Gerard, who had not been depressed in the time of his trial, was not unduly elated in the hour of his vindication.
In both cases, he felt that the will of God had been fulfilled, and that was sufficient for him.
Saint Gerard Majella


"he remained silent, following the example of his Divine Master." Good point, but Jesus didn't always remain silent when accused: John 8:49: "Jesus answered: I have not a devil: but I honour my Father, and you have dishonoured me."
